# How to pass an array from Bazel cli to rules?

Tags: bazel

Let's say I have a rule like this.

```
foo(
    name = "helloworld",
    myarray = [
        ":bar",
        "//path/to:qux",
    ],
)
```

In this case, `myarray` is static. 
However, I want it to be given by cli, like

`bazel run //:helloworld --myarray=":bar,//path/to:qux,:baz,:another"`

How is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get exactly what you're asking for, Bazel would need to support `LABEL_LIST` in Starlark-defined command line flags, which are documented here:

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.1.0/skylark/lib/config.html

and here: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.1.0/skylark/config.html

Unfortunately that's not implemented at the moment.

If you don't actually need a list of labels (i.e., to create dependencies between targets), then maybe `STRING_LIST` will work for you.

If you do need a list of labels, and the different possible values are known, then you can use `--define`, `config_setting()`, and `select()`:

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.1.0/configurable-attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

The question is, what are you really after. Passing variable, array into the `bazel build/run` isn't really possible, well not as such and not (mostly) without (very likely unwanted) side effects. Aren't you perhaps really just looking into passing arguments directly to what is being run by the `run`? I.e. pass it to the executable itself, not bazel?

There are few ways you could sneak stuff in (you'd also in most cases need to come up with a syntax to pass data on CLI and unpack the array in a rule), but many come with relatively substantial price.

- You can define your array in a `bzl` file and load it from where the rule uses it. You can then dump the `bzl` content rewriting your build/run configuration (also making it obvious, traceable) and load the bits from the rule (only affecting the rule loading and using the variable). E.g, `BUILD` file:

  ```
  load(":myarray.bzl", "myarray")
  foo(
      name = "helloworld",
      myarray = myarray,
      ],
  )
  ```

  And you can then call your build:

  ```
  $ echo 'myarray=[":bar", "//path/to:qux", ":baz", ":another"]' > myarray.bzl
  $ bazel run //:helloworld
  ```

  Which you can of course put in a single wrapper script. If this really needs to be a bazel array, this one is probably the cleanest way to do that.
- [`--workspace_status_command`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--workspace_status_command): you can collection information about your environment, add either or both of the resulting files (depending on whether the inputs are meant to invalidate the rule results or not, you could use volatile or stable status files) as a dependency of your rule and process the incoming file in the what is being executed by the rule (at which point one would wonder why not pass it to as its command line arguments directly). If using stable status file, also each other rule depending on it is invalidated by any change.
- You can do similar thing by using [`--action_env`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--action_env). From within the executable/tool/script underpinning the rule, you can directly access defined environmental variable. However, this also means environment of each rule is affected (not just the one you're targeting); and again, why would it parse the information from environment and not accept arguments on the command line.
- There is also [`--define`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--define), but you would not really get direct access it's value as much as you could `select()` a choice out of possible options.